# How to minify, uglify, comiple and clearly make view source to be the most unclearly to decrease hackers readability?

Tags: html, security, gulp

My view source code looks like this:

[image: Click here to view the example]

While its like an open book - an hacker can just read it with a glass of coffee, very comfort and understand everything he needs and play with it.

While Facebook, in constrain, source code makes the hacket SWAT! in order to understand something. Which reduce 90% of browser injections.

See the image below of FB view source:

[image]

How did they do this?
It's like a tornado!

Comment: All you can is to remove white spaces between html tags but any better editor can reformat the html back to structured and indented form.

Comment: The two sources are different - first is HTML and the second is JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=gulp+html+uglify&oq=gulp+html+uglify

Comment: @ino that is what I am saying, in the whole page you will just couple of html tags but tons of unrelated code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the readability of the code, one can:

- Remove all spaces
- Rename all variables and method names to arbitrary single-letter idenifiers
- (advanced) encode strings
- (even more advanced) encode the entire method

What facebook does there is *not* really advanced, google is much uglier still. 
Be aware though that neither of this will prevent any malicious user to try to hack your site. Obfuscation (that's what these concepts are named) does not technically improve security. You have to ensure your backend is not vulnerable when it gets requests that would not normally be possible using your HTML.

Comment: Yes my backend is Node.js RESTapi server. I am validating each input or anything received from the client. I am just wonder how the big sites make everything to be so complicated in the view source.
I am not asking this to make the code more secure, I know that to make it more secure there are lots of other practical ways, but, I just do not want everybody to read it, to see the way I work, maybe some competitor which have a site serving same services like mine or other developers.. Just to keep my code more private.

Comment: @Raz: Ok, then this kind of obfuscation is the way to go. The other answer suggests a framework for this. Of course you would only apply that before your code goes life, not on the original code you work with.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple frameworks available online for minifying your code.

I would recommend you to go with uglify-js.

Click [uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) to take a look at it. You need to install [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) to proceed with it.